# PL SQL - newbie - MAX fron table and avg

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of account numbers by date and 24 hourly intervals

ACCT# ; Date ; hour1, hour2, hour3......hour24

there could be as many as 365 days per account# I would like to find the average of all the intervals as well as the as max interval for each acct#. I tried to add sample data but since it is my first post I can't attach it (need+10 posts) –

"customer_number"   "date"  "est_hb_0000"   "est_hb_0100"   "est_hb_0200"   "est_hb_0300"   "est_hb_0400"   "est_hb_0500"   "est_hb_0600"   "est_hb_0700"   "est_hb_0800"   "est_hb_0900"   "est_hb_1000"   "est_hb_1100"   "est_hb_1200"   "est_hb_1300"   "est_hb_1400"   "est_hb_1500"   "est_hb_1600"   "est_hb_1700"   "est_hb_1800"   "est_hb_1900"   "est_hb_2000"   "est_hb_2100"   "est_hb_2200"   "est_hb_2300"

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Account# DATE , hour 1 , Hour 2, ,,,,,,,hour 24

Comment: Please provide some more explanation.

Comment: supply (a) sample data, and (b) expected result. what you have put in the question as data just isn't sufficient

Comment: Slim,   You are evidently working with a table where there is a column for each hour interval.    This 'horizontal' approach makes Averages, Sums, Min, Max and other aggregate functions nearly impossible.

Consider instead a table structure such as CustNum, Date, HourOfDay, and THEN NumAccts.    Once the data is structured this way,  and populated, you would have 24 rows of data for each Customer for each day.   Then you can use TOP 10, MAX, MIN and other functions with ease.

Comment: oops...you are on PL/SQL...so no...the TOP 10 wont work for you.  But this should :      Where RowCount < 11 order by NumAccts Desc

Answer (score 0):

This SQL should get you close, after you have restructured and populated the table.

```
Select Customer, Date, HourOfDay, NumAccts
From ActivityStats
Where Customer = 'zzz'
  and Date = 'Dt'
  and RowNumber < 11
Order By NumAccts Desc
```

Comment: In the Process of - Union All - all  the hour columns- I cam across the issue last night  it was a nightmare trying to get the AVG  of the 24 columns -thank you- I will let you know how it goes.